# You should have a com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity with the scheme:XXXXXXXX

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload a text file to my Dropbox, but it shows an error in manifest.
This is my  **Manifest file** and **the logcat error**, what am I doing wrong can anyone help me please...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.ondropbox"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ondropbox.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


            <data android:scheme="db-5qiq4z06ikagxfb" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

The Error is:

```
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: URI scheme in your app's manifest is not set up correctly. You should have a com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity with the scheme: db-5qiq4z06ikagxfb**
```

What should I do?

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

because you are missing to add activity,,,

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.ondropbox.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="db-5qiq4z06ikagxfb" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and you are done.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. But if i am not placing **android:name="com.example.ondropbox.MainActivity"** my MainActivity.java will not be get open (executed). It is like a **path** we are giving to open our program.
Please reply @Innocent Killer

Comment: No, you don't have to remove your mainactivity tag. wait i will update full code.

Comment: Please add all that things in my Manifest (My Post) and reply.
thank you.

Comment: I have updated my answer, just change some activity name and other thing as per your requirement, and add your dropbox key inside com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity this activity not inside your mainActivity.

Comment: VEEEEEEEEEERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY THANK you Sir........
I was trying from last 2 days for it...

Comment: Glad to help you. just accept the answer if it helped you by clicking right button.

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar issue after migrating my app from Dropbox API v1 to v2. I used an official tutorial for migration - https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/migration-guide, but there are no word about Android, only basic examples in Java. So I opened this GitHub repo and used it as reference - https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/android.

But in new API they changed a package of `AuthActivity` and I forgot to check, so had a Runtime crash - `Unable to find com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity`.

The solution is to change old package to new one - `com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity` to `com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity`.